# Google chart geomap highlight region

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, charts, google-visualization, geomap

I have used google chart for Geo-map in angular js.

I have used angular-google-chart plugin.

I have used below options.

```
geo = {
            type: 'GeoChart',
            options: {
                width: '100%',
                height: 300,
                chartArea: { left: 10, top: 10, bottom: 0, height: "100%" },
                colorAxis: { colors: ['#aec7e8', '#1f77b4'] },
                displayMode: 'regions',
                resolution : 'provinces'
            }
}
```

[image: google chart]

Above is the chart i have displayed. when i mouse hover on region i see pointer on footer bar which displays 1-7.

Is there any way to highlight regions when mouse hover on footer bar?